# GRID // dont know how to convert my css-/html-code into a more responsive design via grid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

## Hi everyone

Im a noob and struggle to make the webpage responsive.

**Problem:**

Im using a grid-area style. I **want the columns to stack responsivly over each other** as soon the window getting smaller.
In my case less than 975px width.
My code is a mess rn because Im trying different approches atm. So I hope its readable enough.

**Screenshots:**

[Desktop -> works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwuEx.png)

[SmallerScreen -> dosen't stack on each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwYSr.png)

**Here is the [github page](https://github.com/30nImA87/news-homepage-main/tree/nimaTry):**

I don't include the code into here, so you can check it in context.

**My approach**: YOU CAN FIND IT @ LINE 70!

**from here**...

```css
body{
  grid-template-areas:  "head   head" 
                        "main   new"
                        "foot   foot"
                        "attri  attri";
}
```

**to here...**

```css
@media screen and ( max-width: 975px ) {
body{
grid-template-areas:  "head"
                      "main" 
                      "new"
                      "foot"
                      "attri";
  }}
```

**Thank you** very much for your time and help.

Nima

Comment: This kinda works, but the **problem is reversed now**! xD so i think im doing something wrong with the *mediaquery*
**after I swaped the *body{}* parts** and **changed the *mediaquery***

from

```css

@media screen and ( max-width: 975px ) {...}
```

to

```css
@media screnn and ( min-width: 975px ) {...}
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the deployment? Or add it to codepen?

Comment: I got the solution, but if you wish i can add it to codepen. But it might take a while as i don't know how to properly use CodePen for providing the code to the public.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out yesterday what my error was.
I did place the @media tag before the class definition.

Always place the media query at really last lines of code so you avoid errors.

I hope this will help future me's who got stuck in the same path.

**If your *@media* query dosen't apply the characteristics of the device ( such as its screen size, resolution, and pixel density etc. ), place it to the bottom of your code.**

hf gl

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I will asap sir